# Программно продлить переменную на одну неделю Javascript

Tags: javascript, unixtimestamp

Есть такой код, который используется для продления переменной на неделю. Использую inix stamp:

```
"type": {"utc": 1520294399000},
            /* convertor unix time online - http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm*/
```

Как сделать проверку и выводить переменную которая каждую неделю будет меняться. До следующего понедельника.

Сейчас я вручную прибавляю неделю^

было:

```
1515801599000
```

прибавил неделю:

```
1520294399000
```

Comment: Вы сейчас о куках говорите?

Comment: @EgorRandomize нет, просто переменная js и простая проверка. если просто прибавлять семь дней, не учитывая 30 31 день, не пойму как это сделать.

Comment: @stack-tx, я правильно Вас понял, что вы хотите увеличить численное значение переменной на неделю. то бишь на число секунд в неделе?

Comment: правильно. мне нужен каждый понедельник. то есть проверять, до следующего понедельника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date();
//Считаем день недели
var today = (1 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7;
//Если сегодня понедельник, то прибавляем к дате 7 дней, иначе столько, сколько нужно 
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (today == 0 ? 7 : today));
//Выводим d
console.log(d)
```